# How to access HDD if it cannot be mounted

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, macbook-pro, file-recovery

So my MBP crashed the other day and when I attempted to reboot it went straight to Disk Utility X. When I used Disk Utility to repair my HDD it says "Disk cannot be repaired, backup as much as possible and reformat." I did a little research and found that you can install an OS on an external HD and recover files from the HDD.

That's where I encountered the issue. I'm now running OS on my external HD and my MBP seems to not able to register HDD on the computer. I've attempted to use Terminal to access the HDD and when I do "mount /dev/disk0s2" it says "Volume on disk0s2 failed to mount" It see that the HDD existed but cannot mount it or repair it.

Does that mean my HDD is fried? :((((( PLEASE HELPPPPPP!!! THANK YOUUUUUUU

Comment: In Disk Utility running off the External Drive, can you create an image of the drive? Sounds fried to me unfortunately, but take into account the answer below if possible.

Answer (score 1):

We used to fix these drives by pulling them from the machine and mounting them in an external case.  It gave us the ability to listen to the drive and hear what's happening with it.

Pull the drive and put it into a USB enclosure and mount the new drive with OS in the case as primary.  If the drive is making a steady clicking noise then it maybe shot.  Some of those drives can come back for a while (I have one that came back to life in a very hot running, from BOINC packets, Dell m6300 that warmed the drive up to 45 C but it'll never be reliable again) when put into a hot environment.

If it sounds normal then start up the new OS on the new drive and attach the old drive in external USB enclosure and perform repair from there.

There are various data recovery utilities but I'm only familiar with Windows and DOS (yes, some of the DOS versions still perform their duties) versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the disk into a usb caddy and then plugging into a machine running Ubuntu. I had exactly the same issue as you and the disk could be read perfectly under Linux.